# Translating SQLite nested queries into parse queries

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-sqlite

**Take the following where clause for a cursor:**

```
whereClause = DBHelper.SCHEDULE_DAY + " = '" + dayOfTheWeek + "' AND "
                      + DBHelper.SCHEDULE_STARTTIME + " = (SELECT " + DBHelper.SCHEDULE_STARTTIME
                      + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SCHEDULE + " WHERE " + DBHelper.SCHEDULE_DAY
                      + " = '" + dayOfTheWeek + "' AND " + DBHelper.SCHEDULE_STARTTIME + " < "
                      + (currenttime - 100)  + " ORDER BY "
                      + DBHelper.SCHEDULE_STARTTIME + " DESC LIMIT 1)";
```

**Which, written in SQL syntax, would be:**

> SELECT className FROM SCHEDULE WHERE day = "Tuesday" AND startTime =
>   (SELECT startTime FROM SCHEDULE WHERE day =  "Tuesday" AND startTime <
>   1200 ORDER BY startTime DESC LIMIT 1);

is it possibly in Parse Queries to nest parameters?  With the LocalData store feature, I'd like to remove my SQLite databases in favor of the LocalDatastore, as I already am using it for temporary caching.   Maybe I'm overthinking the translation from SQLite to Parse, but this is what I've come up with so far:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("classes");
    query.whereEqualTo("day", dayOfTheWeek);
    // What to add in here for time?
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> classList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
           //Do something with results
        } else {
           // Failed
        }
    }
});
```

Classes last for an hour exact, hence the currenttime -100 (IE if it's 8AM, look for classes starting at 0700 or before (0800-100). Is the answer a compound Parse Query, such as the following?:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> startHour = ParseQuery.getQuery("classes");
startHour.whereEqualTo("day", dayOfTheWeek);
query.whereLessThan("startHour", currenttime -100);
query.addDescendingOrder("startHour");
query.setLimit(1);

List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(startHour);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
mainQuery.whereEqualTo("day", dayOfTheWeek);
mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    // result is the classes that start at or before the hour found
  }
});
```

Big thanks to the community on StackOverflow for all the help they provide!

UPDATE:

I managed to solve this, sort of, using two parseQueries:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> startHour = ParseQuery.getQuery("schedule");
    startHour.whereEqualTo("day", "Thursday");
    startHour.whereLessThan("startHour", (currenttime - 100) / 100 * 100);
    startHour.orderByDescending("startHour");
    startHour.fromPin("schedule");
    startHour.setLimit(1);
    startHour.fromLocalDatastore();
    startHour.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        // result is the classes that start at or before the hour found
        for (ParseObject object : results) {
          time = object.getInt("startHour");
        }

        // Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, "time query: " +
        // String.valueOf(time),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("schedule");

    mainQuery.whereEqualTo("day", "Thursday");
    mainQuery.fromPin("schedule");
    mainQuery.whereGreaterThan("startHour", time - 5);
    mainQuery.whereLessThan("startHour", time + 5);
    // mainQuery.whereEqualTo("startHour", 1930);
    mainQuery.fromLocalDatastore();
    mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        // result is the classes that start at or before the hour found
        if (e == null) {
          Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, "array values: " + String.valueOf(results.size()),
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          for (ParseObject object : results) {
            Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, "array values: " + object.getString("class"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, "array values: " +
        // String.valueOf(results.size()),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
```

I seem, however, to have identified a problem.  If I put a constraint in the second query for

> mainQuery.whereEqualTo("startHour", time);

It returns 0 results.   If I change add the following two constraints, it works:

```
mainQuery.whereGreaterThan("startHour", time-5);
mainQuery.whereLessThan("startHour", time+5);
```

So why is it that if i do GT and LT, it works, but not equal to? I've posted this as a bug on parse's site, and here is a screenshot of my databrowser showing the two entries i expect returned:
[image]

Comment: Nevermind, still doesn't work when i put the time variable back in.  I did some testing with Toasting the "time-5" and it shows as "-5", telling me at some point time is getting set back to zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid bug and has been addressed with facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335038033327436/

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out part of the problem, though there is still a bug. There appeared to be a timing issue with running two "findInBackground" operations, where the second query actually ran during or before the first one.   This was evident when I tried toasting "time -5", I would get a popup indicating "-5", instead of a 4 digit time, indicating the time variable had not been set yet from the first query.

I ended up solving that part by changing the first query to a regular query (ParseQuery.find()).  This consistently gave me the time value I needed for the second query.

There still seems to be an issue using "whereEqualTo" more than once, so I've had to work around this with a GreaterThan and a LessThan clause.  below is my code that works as I want it to

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> startHour = ParseQuery.getQuery("schedule");
    startHour.whereEqualTo("day", dayOfTheWeek);
    startHour.whereLessThan("startHour", (currenttime - 100));
    startHour.orderByDescending("startHour");
    startHour.fromPin("schedule");
    startHour.setLimit(1);
    startHour.fromLocalDatastore();
    startHour.clearCachedResult();
    List<ParseObject> results;
    try {
      results = startHour.find();
      ParseObject result = results.get(0);
      Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, String.valueOf(result.getInt("startHour")),
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      timeT = result.getInt("startHour");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("schedule");

    mainQuery.whereEqualTo("day", dayOfTheWeek);
    mainQuery.fromPin("schedule");

    mainQuery.whereGreaterThan("startHour", timeT - 5);

    mainQuery.whereLessThan("startHour", timeT + 5);
    // mainQuery.whereEqualTo("startHour", timeT); //This doesn't work...duhh
    mainQuery.fromLocalDatastore();
    mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        // result is the classes that start at or before the hour found
        if (e == null) {

          for (ParseObject object : results) {
            Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, "array values: " + object.getString("class"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(Dialog_Checkin.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    });
```